# Estimate time complexity of a graph algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

I have an undirected graph G = (V, E) represented by an adjacency matrix. For each edge I must compute its weakness. The weakness *d* is computed as follow:
[image: weakness]
Where Nx is the set of direct nodes of x (with direct nodes I mean the nodes with a path of 1 from x).
I've wrote this algorithm, but I'm not sure about how to evaluate its complexity.

```
float **graph_weakness(struct graph *g)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int n = g->n;
    struct edge *edge;
    int rel_union;
    int rel_intersect;
    int idx;
    float **m = graph_to_matrix(g);

    /* complessità: O(|V|/2|E|) */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        edge = g->nodes[i]->edges;
        while (edge != NULL) {
            idx = edge->idx;
            if (m[i][idx] == MATRIX_SET) {
                rel_union = 0;
                rel_intersect = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    if (m[i][j] != 0.0 || m[idx][j] != 0.0) {
                        rel_union++;
                    }
                    if (m[i][j] != 0.0 && m[idx][j] != 0.0) {
                        rel_intersect++;
                    }
                }
                m[i][idx] = 1 - (float) rel_intersect / rel_union;
                m[idx][i] = m[i][idx];
            }
            edge = edge->next;
        }
    }

    return m;
}
```

The algorithm iterates over the edges and for each edge computes the intersection and union of the sets using a loop from 1..|V|.
Tha matrix is symmetric so the computation is made on half the edges.
The complexity should therefore be O(|E|/2 * |V|) = O(|E|*|V|), am I right?

Comment: "Where Nx is the set of direct edges of node x." - what does that mean? The edges emanating from x? Terminating at x?

Comment: Sorry I mean "the set of direct nodes of x" (with direct nodes I mean the nodes with a path of 1 from x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
float **m = graph_to_matrix(g);
```

is probably *Θ(|V| |E|)*

(it depends on your matrix library).

---

(Perhaps somewhat contrary to the statement in your question), the algorithm starts by looping over all nodes

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

For each node, it iterates over all neighbors

```
while (edge != NULL) {
```

and for each neighbor, it iterates over all nodes again

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
```

So, assuming your graph has adjacency-list representation, this first + second loop are run *O(|E| + |v|)* times altogether, and each iteration iterates over *|V|* items.

---

This algorithm is *O((|E| + |V|) |V|)*, therefore.

Comment: Since I'm using an adjacency list for iterating over the edges, couldn't i see the first + second loop as a single iteration with cost O(|E|)?

Comment: Almost. The cost is *|V| + |E|*: you're going over each node once, and each edge once. The answer takes this into account.

Comment: Ok, understood. Supposing I'm using an adjacency list (with the same two loops) for the `graph_to_matrix` function, the cost of setting the 1's in the matrix shouldn't be O(|V| + |E|) too?

Comment: Yeah, but it's swallowed up by the cost of iterating over all nodes (for the second time), so it doesn't alter the overall complexity.

Comment: I guess It should be `O(|V| +|E|*|V|)` as it will Iterate all node for every edge and traverse all the vertices.